# Disable Scrollbar conditionally without javascript

Tags: css

i want to hide the scrollbar conditionally i.e. i want to hide the scrollbar of the body when javascript is disabled and enabling it when javascript is enabled because in my page iam showing an message when javascript is disabled and not allowing to user to do anything by graying out the whole screen but as the height for different pages are different so iam using a big height in that case the scrollbar is creating problem in case of small height pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a style inside the `noscript` tag.

Just do as shown below;

```
<noscript>
     <style>
         body { width:100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden; }
     </style>
</noscript>
```